# Document Library last accessed datetime

Tags: list, document-library

Any way to get a SharePoint 2013 Document Library last accessed datetime programmatically for a user ?
When I get Audit log report for site collection there are event occurred times but this has to done in manually. Is there any way to extract only user's last view of Document Library programmatically.

Comment: I tested this script and It seems to not work... Every site has exactly the same last access date 2018-01-07:00:00:00:000. I'm on a 2013 farm in sql 2014

Answer (score 1):

Below is shown SQL Server writing some SQL code. You can create SSRS with code and include in your application

```
SELECT FullUrl AS 'Site URL', TimeCreated,DATEADD(d,DayLastAccessed + 65536, CONVERT(datetime, '1/1/1899', 101)) AS lastAccessDate FROM Webs WHERE (DayLastAccessed <> 0) AND (FullUrl LIKE N'sites/%') ORDER BY lastAccessDate
```

You need to run this query against the specific content database and extract the report.

1. Login to your SQL box
2. Open SQL Server management studio
3. Click on “New Query” from the top
4. Change the database from the dropdown
5. Select your content database
6. Paste the above query in the query box
7. Select it (control A)
8. Execute it from the top.
9. You will get the report in the bottom section. That’s it- You are done.

Reference :- http://sharepointknowledgebase.blogspot.com/2014/02/last-access-date.html

Comment: this solution for site collection does this apply to lists as well ? and does this gives real time results ? I mean SharePoint timer jobs executes particular time for a day to insert logs to DB.